# Insert content in static containers of a templated class prior to main

Tags: c++, templates

I want to build a templated class with only static data members and functions, basically a collection of functions with some internal data I want to fill in various parts of the code. I am trying to insert content into the data members prior to arriving in `main()`. This works fine for non-templated classes, but for templated classes I can't seem to figure out how to make it work.

Here's the code:

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Foo{
private:
    static std::vector<unsigned> content;
public:
    static void insert(unsigned u){ content.push_back(u); }
    static size_t size(){ return content.size(); }
};
std::vector<unsigned> Foo::content=std::vector<unsigned>();

struct Bar{ 
    Bar(){ Foo::insert(0);  }
} bar; 
// this works fine in gcc, but is this consistent or am I lucky?
// Foo::content will contain 0 prior to entering main

template <typename T>
class Quux{
private:
    static std::vector<T> content;
public:
    static void insert(T t){ content.push_back(t); }
    static size_t size(){ return content.size(); }
};
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> Quux<T>::content=std::vector<T>();

struct Wobble{ 
    Wobble(){ Quux<unsigned>::insert(0);    }
} wobble;  
// this does not work
// Quux<unsigned>::content will be empty prior to entering main

int main(){

    std::cout << Foo::size() << std::endl;  
    // outputs 1, as desired

    std::cout << Quux<unsigned>::size() << std::endl;   
    // outputs 0, makes me sad :(

    Wobble wobble2;
    std::cout << Quux<unsigned>::size() << std::endl;   
    // outputs 1, as desired
}
```

Output:

```
1
0
1
```

`Foo` is the non-templated class and I can insert stuff in `Foo::content` prior to running `main()` via the struct `Bar` just fine. I hope this is consistent behaviour instead of me being lucky?

When I try to do the same thing for a templated class `Quux<T>`, however, it seems that I have to wait until `main()` before I can add stuff. Can someone explain why this is necessary and (hopefully) a way around that? I assume it has something to do with the time of template instantiation, but I can't figure out exactly why. I would expect `Quux<unsigned>` to be fully available after the following:

```c
struct Wobble{ 
    Wobble(){ Quux<unsigned>::insert(0); }
} wobble;
```

What am I missing here? Why can I add content to the non-templated class prior to `main` via `bar` but can't I do the same through `wobble`? Is there any way to get the same behaviour as in `Foo` and `Bar` with templated classes?

Comment: What happens if you remove the initializer from `Quux<>::content`? Vectors will always initialize as empty.

Comment: @arne everything blows up! `/tmp/cc9EjNZp.o: In function `Quux<unsigned int>::insert(unsigned int)':
sscce.cpp:(.text._ZN4QuuxIjE6insertEj[Quux<unsigned int>::insert(unsigned int)]+0x13): undefined reference to `Quux<unsigned int>::content'
/tmp/cc9EjNZp.o: In function `Quux<unsigned int>::size()':
sscce.cpp:(.text._ZN4QuuxIjE4sizeEv[Quux<unsigned int>::size()]+0x5): undefined reference to `Quux<unsigned int>::content'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
`

Comment: If you add an explicit instantiation of `Quux<unsigned>` *before* the definition of `class Wobble`, it works as intended.

Comment: @MarcClaesen: Oh dear. Was just a shot in the dark anyway. DyP is most probably right.

Comment: @arne I'm not sure; the Standard says something about explicitly *specialized*, and mentions explicitly *instantiated* as unordered initialization.

Comment: @arne The initializer IMO *is* superfluous; it initializes a temporary and copies/moves that into the initialized `vector`; but the copy/move will most probably be elided. With my g++4.8, it works as well (= not at all, but doesn't crash) w/o the initializer, but AFAIK we're already in UB-land.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[basic.start.init]/2

> Definitions of explicitly specialized class template static data members have ordered initialization. Other class template static data members (i.e., implicitly or explicitly instantiated specializations) have unordered initialization. [...] Variables with ordered initialization defined within a single translation unit shall be initialized in the order
>   of their definitions in the translation unit. [...]  Otherwise, the unordered initialization of a variable is indeterminately sequenced with respect to every other dynamic initialization.

As far as I understand that, you have undefined behaviour, as the initialization of `Quux<unsigned>::content` is indeterminately sequenced with the initialization of `wobble`:

[intro.execution]/13

> Evaluations A and B are indeterminately sequenced when either A
>   is sequenced before B or B is sequenced before A, but it is unspecified which.

That is, it is possible your program accesses a not dynamically initialized `Quux<unsigned>::content`.

Explicit specialization solves the problem.

---

Note that before any dynamic initialization, zero-initialization occurs. Therefore, it is possible to use pointers and dynamic memory allocation to overcome the problem of initialization order:

```
template <typename T>
class Quux{
private:
    static std::vector<T>* content;
    static void create() { if(!content) content = new std::vector<T>; };
public:
    static void insert(T t){ create(); content->push_back(t); }
    static size_t size(){ create(); return content->size(); }
};
template <typename T>
std::vector<T>* Quux<T>::content;
```

This will introduce a "memory-leak" at the end of the program; if that's a problem you might add a deleter object, i.e. another static data member that deletes `content` on its own destruction (half an RAII).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and particularly the standard quotes. I understand now! I will use dynamic allocation along with a deleter object, it seems elegant to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can add explicit template instantiation prior to usage in Wobble `template class Quux<unsigned>;`
Something like this
http://ideone.com/clone/mkJo0W

Comment: Why does that make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

You should add explicit instantiation of content vector for unsigned before defining first wobble, i.e.

```
template<>
std::vector<unsigned> Quux<unsigned>::content=std::vector<unsigned>();
```

Then it works like intended, outputting 1, 1, 2.